# Perl: Get the user name and group name from stat commad

Tags: linux, perl, file, unix, stat

Here is the code snippet I am using and I am unable to get the user name and group name for the required file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use File::stat;
$somedir = '/var/vob/icc_shantesh/';
$file = $somedir."power.log";

my $gid = stat($file1)->gid;
my $uid = stat($file1)->uid;

print "User Id : $uid Group Id : $gid";
```

ouptut:
      User id : 23489
      Group Id : 29023

How can I get user name and group name as well ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
getgrgid($gid);
getpwuid($uid);
```

might be useful (get group added, it was wrong)

**Update**

I changed your code to this and it worked

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use strict;
 use Data::Dumper;
 use File::stat;
 $somedir = '/var/vob/icc_shantesh/';
 $file = $somedir."power.log";

 my ($gid) = getgrgid(stat($file)->gid);
 my ($uid) = getpwuid(stat($file)->uid);

 print "User Id : $uid Group Id : $gid";
```

Comment: do i need to mention any perl module for above mentioned functions ?

Comment: Note that it returns an array and the first element contains the name. Hence I used like `my ($gid) = ...` to catch the first element only.

Comment: Thanks its working only for user id  not the group id any idea why ?

Comment: hmm it worked for me. However, try using `getgrgid` to retrieve the group name. You can find similar other methods here http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/functions/getgrgid.html